# Many callback buffers for camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera, bytebuffer, addcallback, previewcallback

I'm working with camera in Android and I'm using preview callback with byte buffer. If I call the function addCallbackBuffer many times, it will add several buffers. In what order will be used added buffers when the catching frame - in order of adding or in a chaotic order?